# Response.write works in Local not working in IIS7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

My application previously working fine in Windows 7 IIS 7.5 . But the application is changed to another PC contains same configuration. But here 'Response.Write' is not working.But the same code works fine locally in development PC and also worked fine in previous PC.
 The code

```
protected void ReportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('ReportPage.aspx?UserID=admin','_blank','width=1000,height=800,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');</script>");
}
```

I want to open another window of ReportPage.aspx. Is there any setting to change in IIS 7.5.

Comment: Did you check if the code was written to the html? Because I sincerely doubt Response.Write does not work. It it far more likely that the browser is blocking the popup.

Comment: But from .aspx page,im invoking another popup.it is working.  I want to send UserID to the browser address so i used Response.write from aspx.cs file .